The decomposition of the tensor square of the standard representation of $\mathfrak{S}_d$
In the representation theory of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_d$, I would like to have a simple proof of the fact that for $d \geq 4$,
$$
{V_{(d - 1, 1)}}^{\otimes 2} \cong V_{(d)} \oplus V_{(d - 1, 1)} \oplus V_{(d - 2, 2)} \oplus V_{(d - 2, 1, 1)}
$$
Here, for $\lambda$ a partition of $d$, $V_\lambda$ denotes the corresponding irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{S}_d$.
The proof that I have seen proceeds as follows: Apply the Branching rule twice by considering any irreducible representation $V_\lambda$, restricting to $\mathfrak{S}_{d - 1}$ and then inducing back up to $\mathfrak{S}_d$. Then use the Remark below Exercise 3.16 from Fulton & Harris to see that $\operatorname{Ind} \operatorname{Res} V_\lambda$ is isomorphic to $V_\lambda \otimes P$, where $P$ is the permutation representation of $\mathfrak{S}_d$ acting on $\{1, \ldots, d\}$. Note that $P \cong V_{(d)} \oplus V_{(d - 1, 1)}$. Note that both sides of the resulting equation contain $V_\lambda$ as a direct summand and subtract it from both sides. Hence we obtain the following formula
$$
V_{(d - 1, 1)} \otimes V_\lambda \cong \bigoplus\limits_\mu V_\mu \oplus {V_\lambda}^{\oplus (C_\lambda - 1)}
$$
where the direct sum is over all partitions $\mu$ which can be obtained by moving a corner cell of $\lambda$ and $C_\lambda$ is the number of corner cells in $\lambda$. Now take $\lambda = (d - 1, 1)$, where, for $d \geq 4$, we have $C_\lambda = 2$ and the allowed $\mu$ are $(d)$, $(d - 2, 2)$ and $(d - 2, 1, 1)$.
Is there a more direct proof?

I'm struggling to guess the meaning of $V, V_{(d)},V_{(d-1,1)}$ etc. and I don't know the searchwords to look it up online. What do you mean here?

@FShrike I've added this information to the question. Thanks. $V_\lambda$ denotes the irreducible representation corresponding to the partition $\lambda$, so for example $V_{(d)}$ is the trivial representation and $V_{(d - 1, 1)}$ is the standard representation.

I just realized that this is Exercise 4.19 in Fulton & Harris
